# Usage of JSTL Function fn:length

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I am working on a defect in which by default all check-box need to be selected, if multiple channels are used. However, currently in case of multiple channels selects the fist channel check-box remains unselected only

THE JSTL code is

```
<label data-use-main="#"
    class="left-align  form-inline checkbox ${fn:length(messageForm.configuredChannels) > 1 ? '' : 'hidden'}">
      <form:checkbox path="emailMessageForm.useMainMessageEmail" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <label>
        <spring:message code="message.use.main.content.email"></spring:message>
      </label>
</label>
```

I m not able to understand how `${fn:length(messageForm.configuredChannels) > 1 ? '' : 'hidden'}">`  works as the checkbox checked condition depends on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`messageForm.configuredChannels` is a collection and the `fn:length()` function is checking to see if the collection contains more than one element.  If the collection contains more than one element the `label` containing the checkbox is displayed and if not it is hidden by adding a css class.

Lets break the expression down:

```
${fn:length(messageForm.configuredChannels) > 1 ? '' : 'hidden'}"

1.  ${}
    This just denotes a JSP EL expression

2.  fn:length(messageForm.configuredChannels) > 1 ? '' : 'hidden'
    This is a ternary operator

3.  fn:length(messageForm.configuredChannels)
    Returns amount of elements in collection
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, however the issues is if collection contains more than one element , the first checkbox is always not checked by default , it should be checked by default.

Comment: Gotcha, you need to use the `value` attribute on the checkbox tag.

Comment: Have you placed a `emailMessageForm` in your model?

Comment: Thanks Kevin , I have SMS, Voice and Email as channels When a user selects SMS, email and Voice then only SMS checkbox is always un-selected and remaining two are checked 
Similarly when Email, SMS, Voice are selected then only Email is un-selected and reaming two are checked

Comment: @ronan I'm slightly confused.  The markup only shows one checkbox.  Is that markup within a for:each?